# Appropiate ways to handle passing of data MySQL->JSON->PHP?

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, datatables

I am using DataTables (a plugin for jQuery) to display some data; this data originates from a MySQL database and some PHP code manipulates it into JSON format in the HTML. I have it all working, but it doesn't seem the appropriate way.

But this is not very effective with jQuery, as I want to do things like dynamic refreshing & the sort.

What's a good way to handle this, besides the way I'm doing it? Other things I have considered is a schedule dumping the SQL to a `data.json` file but I see pitfalls with that as well (a pitfall being the data will not be up to date if say I release the `.json` as an "API").

My current method:

1. HTML form inserts data into MySQL database.
2. Frontpage queries MySQL database for all records.
3. The data from step 2 is converted to JSON using PHP.
4. That JSON is then displayed (on same page) with DataTables.

My concern about my current method is that a full SQL query is performed every page load, as well as dynamic jQuery refreshes on DataTables will not pull new data since that wouldn't perform a SQL query.

My concerns with the methods I'm thinking of:

- Full SQL load on every page hit
- jQuery refresh would not refresh the list, as there's no SQL query performed
- Other method: Scheduling a SQL dump to a .json would not give the up-to-date data always

Answer (score 0):

```
echo json_decode(array('whaever you want'));
```

this sends back the json response which you can read with js

Comment: I already have a method accomplished, I'm looking for better ways to handle this. Can you explain if you mean this as a better method?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
Add the json header to the top of the PHP file.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//Database connection
$conn = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databaseName","Username","Password", array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));

$sql = "SQL STATEMENT";
$results = $conn->query($sql);

//Json Object
$arr = array();

//Loop through results and dump them into the array object
while($obj = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     $arr[] = $obj;
}

//it is important that you have aaData
//refer to datatables API docs
echo '{"aaData":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
```

I assumed you were using MySQL connection library. I have revised this example to use the PDO MySQL connection string. This example is the bare bones, you can build off of it.

Comment: You should refrain from using **mysql_** statements as they are deprecated. Take a look at ***PDO*** or ***mysqli_*** and read up on prepared statements...

Comment: This is intended to be a "flat" JSON file, but dynamically generated?

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you're trying to accomplish is pretty well documented on datatables' website. Perhaps you didn't find the links, so here they are:

http://datatables.net/development/server-side/

http://www.datatables.net/usage/server-side

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

What I usually do is to modify the examples instead of trying to do it from scratch (I would suggest you choose the mysqli example, not the other one). It's pretty straightforward unless you want to join several tables, that takes a little more tweaking...